# Deployment path for deploy java code in AWS

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, cloud

i want to know ,
generally in which scenario we directly create AWS cloud instance by directly uploading java war file
and in which scenario we  first setup and ready server first , by installing all softwares like java,tomkat and then deploy code  in AWS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To deploy Java .war file on an Apache server running on an EC2 instance, you must utilize a combination of Apache Tomcat (as the application server) and the Apache HTTP Server (as the web server) to deploy a.war file. Follow these steps

1. Create an EC2 instance:

- Start an EC2 instance with your choice Linux distribution (for
  example, Amazon Linux, Ubuntu).
  IMP: Check that the EC2 instance's
  security group enables inbound traffic on ports 22 (SSH), 80 (HTTP),
  and 443 (HTTPS).

2. Setup Apache Tomcat:

- Connect to your EC2 instance using SSH from your terminal or an SSH
  client such as PuTTY (Windows users) or use can use AWS cloudshell.
- To Update:
  '**sudo apt update**' (for Ubuntu) or '**sudo yum update**' (for Amazon
  Linux) to update the package list.
- Install Apache Tomcat:
  '**sudo apt install tomcat9**' (for Ubuntu) or '**sudo yum install tomcat**' (for
  Amazon Linux).
- Start Tomcat:
  '**sudo systemctl start tomcat**' (for Ubuntu) or '**sudo service tomcat start**'
  (for Amazon Linux).
- Check the status:
  'sudo systemctl status tomcat' or 'sudo service tomcat status'. Make sure
  it's running correctly.

3. Deploy the .war file:

- Copy your .war file to the Tomcat webapps directory. Assuming your .war file
  is named "myapp.war" and Tomcat 9 is installed, use the following
  command:

  `sudo cp /path/to/myapp.war /var/lib/tomcat9/webapps/`

4. Restart Apache Tomcat:

- After copying the .war file, restart Tomcat to deploy the application:

  `sudo systemctl restart tomcat`

5. Configure Apache HTTP Server as a Reverse Proxy (Optional):

- If you want to access your application via a domain name and port 80 (HTTP),
  you can set up Apache HTTP Server as a reverse proxy. This allows you to use
  Apache as a frontend while forwarding requests to Tomcat in the backend.
- Install Apache HTTP Server: '**sudo apt install apache2**' (for Ubuntu) or
  '**sudo yum install httpd**' (for Amazon Linux).
- Enable the necessary modules: '**sudo a2enmod proxy proxy_http**'.
- Create a virtual host configuration for your domain name. For example,
  create a file named myapp.conf in the '/etc/apache2/sites-available/'
  directory for Ubuntu:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName your_domain.com
    ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/
</VirtualHost>
```

- For Amazon Linux, you can create a similar configuration in the '/etc/httpd/conf.d/' directory.
- Enable the virtual host: sudo a2ensite myapp (for Ubuntu) or sudo systemctl restart httpd (for Amazon Linux).

6. Access the Application:

- If you set up the Apache HTTP Server as a reverse proxy, you can now access your application using your domain name (e.g., **http://your_domain.com**).
- If you didn't set up Apache HTTP Server, you can access the application directly using the Tomcat server's public IP address and port 8080 (e.g., **http://your_ec2_public_ip:8080/myapp**).

Your .war file should now be deployed and accessible through either the Apache HTTP Server or directly via Tomcat, depending on your configuration choices.

Hope this solution Helps.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your question (it's not that clear) sounds like you want to deploy a Java app to AWS Cloud. One way is to write a Spring Boot web app and then bundle that project into a FAT JAR that contains all of the depedencies. Then you can use Elastic Beanstalk to deploy the app to the cloud.

See this Java Developer example, in the [AWS Code Library](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/code-library/latest/ug/what-is-code-library.html), to learn how to perform these tasks. This example app is a basic web app that stores submitted data into an Amazon DynamoDB table. This example walks you step by step through the process.

[Build an application to submit data to a DynamoDB table](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/code-library/latest/ug/dynamodb_example_cross_SubmitDataApp_section.html)